# How to store list in SQL Server from ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have this table in my database and I want to store incoming data:

```
public string Id { get; set; } = default!;
public double? Name { get; set; } = default!;
public string? FamilyName { get; set; } = default!;
public List<Addresses> ClientAddress { get; set; } = default!;
```

Here is my `Addresses` class:

```
public string Id { get; set; } = default!;
public string Address { get; set; } = default!;
```

Now I want to store in database - how should I do with the list?

```
public Task<bool> StoreModel(MainModel mainmodel) 
{
     var listtostore = new MainModelEnity()
                           {
                               Name = mainmodel.Name,
                               FamilyName = mainmodel.FamilyName,
                               ClientAddress = //how should I store here? 
                           }
}
```

Comment: It'd be great if you mentioned what type of database you're trying to use

Comment: @OneCricketeer SQLSERVER

Comment: If you want to store lists, then why are you using a relational database? The "correct" pattern is to store individual rows of `store(address_id=1), store(address_id=2)` in some `store` table, then `address` table has rows for `id=1, id=2`, then you join these to get stores with address info

Comment: @OneCricketeer sorry but i did not get you,from UI get the model with multiple address for a single person,im using relational DB,you are saying i should not use List,but what should i do then?how can i get thoses address store in the db?can you make an example considering my updated question?i really appreciate your help

Comment: I'm saying you should use a foreign key lookup and a SQL-join to get the complete dataset. Doesn't matter that you have a UI component to your app. A store table should only hold store data. Each store has an address, and a list of customers that have ordered something (for example). Each customer has a billing/shipping address. Those should really all be different tables (store, customer, order, address, and maybe others)

Comment: If there are multiple stores, each with different addresses, then each store has some unique identifier, therefore is a unique row, and each row would reference a different address (single string or ID), and **not** a list within the database row

Comment: @OneCricketeer there are clients with different addresses ,I have created another class and table for addresses,my question is when i get data from UI,it contains name,familyName and addresses(lets say 10 addresses)how do you store all this data using linq?

Comment: I don't know LINQ. But the [comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69398019/how-to-store-list-in-sql-server-from-asp-net-core?noredirect=1#comment122662653_69398107) link you to how you define relationships between tables/entity classes

Comment: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-many-relationship-configuration

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant to ask how you store a list in a relational database? Because if if it is a file store or NoSql database then it's fairly easy.

However the short answer is, you don't. It's not what a relational database was meant to do. See this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070384/how-to-store-a-list-in-a-column-of-a-database-table).

That being said, there are ways around it.

1. Store the list as a string:

   ```
    var listString = JsonConvert.Serialize(MyList);
   ```

   Then you can store that string in the database easily
2. Save the list as a file on the server, then just store the location of the file in the database.

Comment: thanks but i created a tables for them ,as you can see addresses class is a foreign key in the main class,so,still i need to do jsonconvert?to be honest i have no idea if my approach is correct

Comment: if i dont wana create a second table i need to do public List<String> ClientAddress ,and when i want to create a DB it throws an error that i cant create table based on list entity

Comment: I don't think OP wants to store JSON or a literal list. The [documentation of EntityFramework shows using Lists to define relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)